# How to get the gridview dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get the titles in my xml file side by side dynamically. I tried but i didn't get the title side by side.

My code:

```
 $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
            var item = $(this).attr("name");

            $("#grid_list").append('<div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c" style="margin: 5px;"><a href="#">"' + item + '"</a></div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c"  style="margin: 5px;"><a href="#"></a></div></div>');

            $("#grid_list").grid('refresh');

        });
```

Desired output: It has to display the items as side by side like "item1" in 1st row 1st column and "item2" in 1st row 2nd column and so on if i get item5 in 3rd row 1st column...after that 3rd row of 2nd column should not be display.And the block should be in square shape in the middle of the screen.

Can anyone help me to get this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You do understand that point of grid view is to spread out full width of the screen? How do you expect if in the middle of the screen?

Comment: yes its spread full width...http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3bD/5/ i'm getting this a side only..

Comment: how many do you want them in a row? Or how many columns?

Comment: in this fiddle it displays all items in the 1st column only..i want to display the items as "item1" in 1column and "item2" in 2 nd column like that./

Comment: So only 2 columns per row?

Comment: yes but it has to end when i get item5 in 3rd row 1st column...after that 3rd row of 2nd column should not be display.

Comment: I'm travelling today, ill help you tomorrow okay?

Comment: ohh...ok no problem..if you dont mind can you give me your mail-id or something else for keep in touch with you for quick discussion...?

Comment: else we'll continue like this only..no problem

Comment: Omarmt [at] gmail . Com

Comment: Thank you very much..Omar..Have a nice Journey..:)

Comment: Thanks :) talk to you soon.